# Receive post with description containing '%' and two letter together

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I have problems with treatment of Post. I received a string with the symbol '%' and two letters together, like 'Geci%de', but on PHP the var_dump I receive a different string, like 'Geci�', if try to use utf8_encode and utf8_decode, however the error continued, the strings resulted were 'GeciÞ' and'Geci?'. How is the better way to convert in the orignal string? I need to use in postgreSQL, it will be in select.
It is uses to treatment:

```
   $data = strip_tags($data);
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 0 ? addslashes($data) : $data;
   $data = preg_replace("@(--|\|)@s", "", $data);
   $data = urldecode($data);   // especific to Ajax
   return utf8_decode($data);
```

Comment: What i suggest is write the content of the post to a file with http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php. Then check the encoding of your data with http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php and make sure you send the data with the correct encoding.

Comment: On really, the software have a treatment for all strings, and this function don't wait for '%' on search. The function uses:
   $data = strip_tags($data);
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 0 ? addslashes($data) : $data;
   $data = preg_replace("@(--|\|)@s", "", $data);
   $data = urldecode($data);
   return utf8_decode($data);

Comment: Please provide more info. What exactly are you trying to do? Send data via form to a php script and the value received is not what was send?? Currently your code only shows string manipulations...

Comment: The string is send from a ajax, at the POST nothing changes, but at PHP, when is receive the data, the String soffers a treatment, like I wrote, and after this convertion the String presents problems. If I don't use the function to treatment nothing occurs. Maybe I won't use the default treatment in this search